# How to do this list/dict comprehension in python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am creating a python dictionary as follows:

```
d= {i : chr(65+i) for i in range(4)}
```

Now output of `d` is `{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D'}`

I have an list of keys that I want to look up as follows:

```
l = [0, 1]
```

Now what I want to do is create another list which contains the values corresponding to these keys and I wanted to know if there was a pythonic way to do so using list or dict comprehensions.

I can do something as follows:

```
[x for x in d[0]]
```

However, I do not know how to iterate over the entries of my list in this setting. I tried:

```
[x for x in d[a] for a in l] # name 'a' not defined
[x for x in d[for a in l]] # invalid syntax
```

Comment: Don't you just want `[d[key] for key in l]`?

Comment: Yup! Of course...Sorry still getting used to this...

Comment: What do you consider "my list" in the last paragraph? Have you tried `[d[a] for a in l]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to iterate over `l`, so use `for element in l`. Then look stuff up in your dictionary in the left-hand side, in the value-producing expression:

```
[d[element] for element in l]
```

Note that a dictionary mapping consecutive integers starting at 0 to letters isn't all that efficient; you may as well make it a list:

```
num_to_letter = [chr(65 + i) for i in range(4)]
```

This still maps `0` to `'A'`, `1` to `'B'`, etc, but without a hashing step.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it - you even solved both problem X and problem Y.